# Range.Find Word VBA: finding heading with specific heading number only works if heading style is specified

Tags: vba, ms-word

I'd like to find the location of a heading that has a specific heading number. E.g. "2.3."
For some reason, I can only find the location of the heading if i specify what Style that heading is going to be. If i don't specify the heading style then I don't get any matches (i.e. `.Execute` is never True).
How can I find the location of a heading without having to specify it's style?

Code that works:

```
Function FindHeadingPos(oRng As Word.Range) As Long
    Dim rng As Word.Range
    With oRng.Find

        .ClearAllFuzzyOptions
        .ClearHitHighlight
        .ClearFormatting
        .Text = ""
        .Forward = True
        .Wrap = 2
        .Format = True
        .Style = "Heading 2,H2 Numb"

        Do While .Execute
            '.Parent contains the found range
            Set rng = .Parent
            If rng.ListFormat.ListString = "2.3." Then
                FindHeadingPos = rng.Start
                Exit Do
            End If
            'below statement seems to prevent code hanging on some headings.
            rng.Collapse Direction:=wdCollapseEnd
        Loop
    End With
End Function
```

Code that doesn't work:

```
Function FindHeadingPos(oRng As Word.Range) As Long
    Dim rng As Word.Range
    With oRng.Find

        .ClearAllFuzzyOptions
        .ClearHitHighlight
        .ClearFormatting
        .Text = ""
        .Forward = True
        .Wrap = 2
        '.Format = True
        '.Style = "Heading 2,H2 Numb"

        Do While .Execute
            '.Parent contains the found range
            Set rng = .Parent
            If rng.ListFormat.ListString = "2.3." Then
                FindHeadingPos = rng.Start
                Exit Do
            End If
            'below statement seems to prevent code hanging on some headings.
            rng.Collapse Direction:=wdCollapseEnd
        Loop
    End With
End Function
```

Comment: Well, you are looking for *no text at all* (`.Text = ""`), which can ever find anything only when there are other clues to go by. `Style` is a clue.

Comment: ah, okay, I presumed that it would find everything instead of finding nothing. Do you have any brief thoughts on an alternative strategy i could try? I tried looping through all the paragraphs but that ran very slowly whereas Find.Execute seems to run much faster.

Comment: i don't know if there's a way to specify an `If InStr(.Style,"Heading") <> 0` statement somewhere that would work...

Comment: You can build a list of styles that are `.InUse` and have `.ParagraphFormat.OutlineLevel` from `wdOutlineLevel1` to `wdOutlineLevel9`, and then repeat your style search for all of them?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks [@GSerg](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11683/gserg) for suggesting the `.ParagraphFormat.OutlineLevel` property.

The code below seems to solve my problem in case it helps anyone else.

```
Function getParaOutlineLevel(headNumberRaw As String) As Integer

    Dim numberOfDecimals As Integer
    numberOfDecimals = Len(headNumberRaw) - Len(Replace(headNumberRaw, ".", ""))
    
    If Not IsNumeric(Left(headNumberRaw, 1)) Then
        getParaOutlineLevel = numberOfDecimals + 5
    Else
        getParaOutlineLevel = numberOfDecimals
    End If

End Function


Function FindHeadingPos(oRng As Word.Range) As Long
    
    Dim headNumber As String
    Dim rng As Word.Range
    
    headNumber = "2.3."
    
    With oRng.Find
        .ClearAllFuzzyOptions
        .ClearHitHighlight
        .ClearFormatting
        .Text = ""
        .Forward = True
        .Wrap = 2
        .Format = True
        .ParagraphFormat.OutlineLevel = getParaOutlineLevel(headNumber)

        Do While .Execute
            '.Parent contains the found range
            Set rng = .Parent
            If rng.ListFormat.ListString = headNumber Then
                FindHeadingPos = rng.Start
                Exit Do
            End If
            'below statement seems to prevent it hanging on some headings.
            rng.Collapse Direction:=wdCollapseEnd
        Loop
    End With

End Function
```